# Rails: Best practice to generate custom HTML in Model?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, video

I let users embed videos from Youtube, Google, Vimeo etc. I thought about the best and most secure approach (I don't want them to be able to include any flash and I also want to restrict the Videosites to exclude free porn websites etc.).

So I thought the best and easiest thing would be to let the user just copy&paste the URL of the video into a text-field, store it in a ExternalVideo Model and then just generate the needed HTML to embed the video.

So my ExternalVideo Model has a function called "embed_html" which should return the proper HTML.

Of course I could do something like this:

```
def embed_html
  # just a very short example to make my point
  "<embed src='#{@video_source}'>" 
end
```

But I think that's bad practice and very unreadable.

My Question: Is there a tool / Gem / Built-in function I can use to generate custom HTML, something like the View Helpers (link_to, image_tag, etc)?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do the following

```
def embed_element(external_video)
  content_tag(:embed, '', :src => external_video.video_source)
end
```

You should probably check the docs for more information on the content tag method.

Also note that the content_tag() method will insert a closing tag. Something you seem to be forgetting...

Comment: thanks, that's what I was looking for. My example ist just to make clear what I want, of course my embed-code will be far more complex and with closing tags...

Comment: You might also want to look into 'markaby' if you want to get much more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You almost answered your question. Use helper method:

```
def embed_html url
  "<embed src='#{url}'>" 
end
```

And use it in view:

```
<%= embed_html @video_source %>
```

Comment: that's not what I asked. I'm looking for a way to generate more complex html code. I didn't want to write the full example in my question, but if you check out the embed code of video sites its much more than the one-liner I posted as an example

Comment: You can with helper method write as complicated html as you want. So I probably don't understand your question and by looking on other answers, they don't understand it too. Maybe give better explanation what you want.

Comment: My point is: I don't want to insert parameters in a long, hard-coded HTML string usign #{param}, because it won't be readable when the embed code is something like this: "<object width="400" height="225"><param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" /><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" /><param name="movie" value="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=5383150&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byline=1&amp;show_portrait=0&amp;color=00ADEF&amp;fullscreen=1" /><embed src="http://vimeo.com/moogaloop.swf?clip_id=5383150&amp;server=vimeo.com&amp;show_title=1&amp;show_byl....

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just write a view helper method that accepts a `ExternalVideo` model instance, asks it for its video URL and then returns the HTML?

Comment: good idea, but my question is: How to return the html without using a very long, ugly string which isn't very readable? This question also applies to the use of a helper method